# Notification mechanisms in objective C, Device orientatoin

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iPad app with many viewcontrollers all loaded programatically from one mainViewcontroller. I do some UI changes when the orientation changes from portrait to landscape. So far I've been handling that notification in the mainVC. My question is :
how does Objective C handle the notification generation process? does it start with the mainVC and then trickle down to child UIControls? should I observe the UIInterfaceOrientation change in all viewcontrollers, or just the main one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

is a delegate to provide the notification on the device orientation change.I think you can implement this in all the viewcontrollers.

but also note that it is viewcontroller specific and it doesnt depend on the parent

Answer (score 0):

The main VC should be responsible for the rotation event management. I usually work this way.

Comment: any reason for that? I mean is it a performance issue? I favor your your way of doing this as opposed to listening in all VC's to rotation changes, but I just want to know which one is more efficient.

Comment: Basically when you need to check for rotation you only need to verify it once: if the main controller is rotating also all of his subviews are rotating. Why you need to check all the items inside a viewcontroller? They could be hundreds!